# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: windows, wcf, service, state, faulted

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

I am getting this error, when windows application is trying to communicate with WCF hosted as Windows Service via wsDualHttpBinding. The WCF is used to communicate with a device over serial port. Windows application used to send command frequently via WCF windows service.

Here's the stack trace:

> stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   GridSplitter.CommandServiceReference.ICommandService.SendToMultipleChannel(String[]
>   channel, Int32[][] locid, String cmd, Int32 cmdData)    at
>   GridSplitter.CommandServiceReference.CommandServiceClient.SendToMultipleChannel(String[]
>   channel, Int32[][] locid, String cmd, Int32 cmdData)    at
>   GridSplitter.MainWindow.bwChkAndSendRedeploy_DoWork(Object sender,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e) : 11/9/2012 11:05:58 AM

1. I couldn't understand why the service is going into faulted state.
2. Should I catch this exception and perform some patch work (if recommended)?
3. Can TCP binding help me to avoid/remove this exception?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is your code is using the instance of the service proxy (Service Reference, generated by SvcUtil or created directly from `ChannelFactory`) after the service call has generated a fault. The way WCF is implemented, you cannot "re-use" a service proxy once a call with that proxy has thrown a fault.

You need to write proper exception handling logic along the [lines shown in this good post](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2007/11/22/117058.aspx) for WCF specific requirements. This needs to be done regardless of the actual binding you configure the proxy to use.

Comment: Hello Sixto, I implemented as suggested by link you provide, till now it's working, Thanks, Thanks a lot. Manoj

Comment: Great news, WCF has some hidden intricacies that pop out a little too often. Glad the code helped and hope you accept my answer. Thanks!